# Getting Failed when Updating Data using Oledb C#

Tags: c#

I have problem when updating data using OleDb in C#. Error says

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Here my code

```
OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
            OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();

            kon.Open();

            if (LimitCB.SelectedItem == "30")
            {
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE [Data] SET [Denom 50]= @den50, [Denom 100]= @den100 WHERE [Limit] = @lim30";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@den50", CRMden50.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@den100", CRMden100.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lim30", 30);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }  
            kon.Close();
```

Comment: [Denom 50] and [Denom 100] are your columns names within table?

Comment: Yes they are @MAdeelKhalid

Answer (score 1):

OleDb does not have named parameters. From the first sentence in the Remarks section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement

Instead of `@name`, it uses the `?` token as parameter placesholders and relies on the ordering of the parameters in the collection to match parameter values to the placeholder.